# Digital signature for java web services

Tags: java, web-services, digital-signature

I'm trying to learn Java web services. To create a simple web service, I've followed [this tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/jax-ws.html) and everything works fine. But now I want to sign the request with a digital signature. How do I do that?

My web service:

```
@WebService(serviceName = "DigSignWebService")
@Stateless()
public class DigSignWebService {

@WebMethod(operationName = "hello")
public String hello(@WebParam(name = "name") String txt) {
    return "Hello " + txt + " !";
}
```

My client:

```
public class DigSignClient {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {        
    String name = "Darth Vader";
    String k = hello(name);
    System.out.println(k);        
}

private static String hello(java.lang.String name) {        
    dgservice.DigSignWebService_Service service = new dgservice.DigSignWebService_Service();
    dgservice.DigSignWebService port = service.getDigSignWebServicePort();
    return port.hello(name);        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution of your problem is in implementation of WS-Security standards. Many frameworks can helps you to solve. Please read [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Security) about this technology, and test it with such frameworks as [axis](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/rampart/), [metro](http://java.globinch.com/enterprise-java/web-services/jax-ws/secure-web-services-signatures-encryption-security-with-metro/) or [wss4j](https://ws.apache.org/wss4j/).